# How to Set and Access Multiple Document Root(Directory) in Apache (Wamp Server)

Tags: php, apache, vhosts, document-root

I tried to add ;

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost 
DocumentRoot "d:\www2\" --> tried d:\www2\
<Directory "d:\www2\">
    Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Directoryindex index.php index.html index.html index.htm index.shtml
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

to httpd-vhosts still I can only acces to "c:/wamp/www" . I want to access with both of them. Please Help me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You can only have one `DocumentRoot`, how else would the server know which location to serve the files from?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one document root per ServerName.

Try to set a virtual host with another server name (like localhost2), and then modify your [**hosts**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to point localhost2 to your local ip (127.0.0.1)

Comment: I tried localhost2 is working fine but i can not access the path which i want.Only access "c:/wamp/www". why ?

Comment: Could you post here your vhosts file?